# How Can I Change the Service Boot Order in ubuntu server 10.04?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to get OpenSIPS working properly. I've got it installed and all is well--except that it won't start at boot because it requires MySQL to run, and for some reason, it is being launched BEFORE MySQLd during init.

What I'd like to do is modify the boot order of my process (/etc/init.d/opensips) so that it is launched AFTER MySQLd, and can work properly.

I've included a pastebin link to my /etc/init.d/opensips file here: http://pastie.org/1236331

I really have no idea. I've searched google for a while, but can't find any answers that work for me.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

As superuser run:

1. update-rc.d -f opensips remove
2. update-rc.d openspips defaults 99

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, I still have the same issue. Also--opensips was already set at 99.

Comment: Remove opensips from startup. Reboot. Is MySQL running? If yes now run /etc/init.d/opensips start. Does it startup? If yes, then what is the startup number that MySQL is associated with? What are the contents (if any) of /etc/defaults/opensips ?

Comment: Ok, I removed both OpenSIPS AND Mysql from startup (no traces of them in /etc/rc*). I rebooted. Mysql is running by default (no idea how?). When I run /etc/init.d/opensips start it starts perfectly and leaves a good log in syslog so I know it connected to mysql. /etc/default/opensips: http://pastie.org/1236504

Comment: To see where mysql might start from, run "grep -rli mysql /etc/rc*"

Comment: It looks like mysql is running via upstart (/etc/init/mysql.conf). Anyway I can force it to run before opensips?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `/etc/init/opensips.conf` then change its `start on` clause to include `and started mysql`. Or if you have `/etc/init.d/opensips` then add `mysql` to its `Should-Start:` and `Should-Stop:` clauses.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have /etc/init.d/opensips, and even if it has mysql in both Should-Start and Should-Stop, it won't work. MySQL is being started via upstart (not initscripts like opensips is), and I think that is the root of the problem. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're running in runlevel 3. Change directory to `/etc/rc3.d`. You'll see various startup scripts for processes. These scripts are run in order, so you want opensips to have a higher number than mysqld. I.e. if mysql looks like this:

```
S64mysqld
```

Then you'd want opensips to look like this:

```
S70opensips
```

Or some other number higher than 64. Hope that helps!

Comment: The command update-rc.d can be used to take care of this. No need to do it by hand.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed the ubuntu-server tag. I come from a Redhat background :)

Comment: I actually don't see mysqld in any of the rcX.d folders. But opensips is in all of them (from rc2 -> rc6) as S99opensips. Any other ideas?

Comment: Check Adamo's answer. If you don't have mysql in your rc.d, run 'update-rc.d mysql defaults'. I wonder how mysql was starting in the first place?

Comment: Since this is Ubuntu, maybe mysql is using Upstart? Look into `/etc/init`.

Comment: Steven, if I look at /etc/init.d/mysql it has a lot of 'upstart' stuff. Is that what is causing my problems? I don't care how its running, as long as mysql starts before opensips :)

Comment: See this guide on upstart http://geeknme.wordpress.com/2009/10/15/getting-started-with-upstart-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1):

If someone is still looking for the answer, they can refer to this link. 
[Manage Linux init or startup scripts, file-rc](http://www.debianadmin.com/manage-linux-init-or-startup-scripts.html)

It did solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.